# Greasemonkey: "waitForKeyElements is undefined"

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to use GreaseMonkey on a page that uses AJAX.  I found what seems to be the solution for waiting and evaluating elements as they appear in "waitForKeyElements"

However, my console returns "waitForKeyElements is undefined"

here's the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SalesForce helper
// @namespace     https://c.na3.visual.force.com*
// @include       https://c.na3.visual.force.com*
// @include       https://na3.salesforce.com/*
// @grant none
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==


if(window.location.href.match("salesforce.com/500?")){
        waitForKeyElements(".listBody div",Greasemonkey_main);  
}

function Greasemonkey_main () {


    alert(window.location.href);
    if(window.location.href.match("salesforce.com/500?")){
        var firstWords = ["Edit","Base","Accelerated","EU","GoLive","Redesign","Report"]
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");    
        for(var i = 0;i < divs.length;i++){     
            var did = divs[i].id;           
            if(did.indexOf("CASES_SUBJECT") > 0){
                var dSpan = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
                var subject = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML.split(" ")[0];  
                if(firstWords.indexOf(subject) < 0){                    
                    //alert("howdy = " + subject);
                    dSpan.style = "background-color:yellow";
                }               
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more information ?

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out.  In all of the research and examples of this function that I found, I never realized that it was a separate script that needed to be included.

```
// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
```

Comment: Even after including it like you show, I had the same problem and found that I had to add: /* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements */ as indicated on https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/553